# Optimal use of multiple interfaces to download a large file (a riff on load balancing)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, load-balancing

Lets assume a simple setup:

1. A linux box with 2 interfaces, each with a 5 mbps download cap, so a theoretical total download bandwidth of 10 mbps.
2. A remote server unlimited in bandwidth holds a file of 1TB.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm under the impression that a typical `rsync` job over ssh would be bound to one interface in this case, so you'd see up to 5 mbps download.

What solutions could one explore to get towards 10 mbps? Network configuration and software (presumably along the lines of BitTorrent) solutions are all welcome as the ultimate goal is an optimal download.

Comment: Debian and derivatives distribute a `mptcpize` command that sets up LD_PRELOAD to patch `socket(f,t,0)` to `socket(f,t,IPPROTO_MPTCP)`. Going to want a reasonably recent (5.13+) kernel.

Comment: Depending on distance, might still be more efficiently solved with *a bicycle and a thumb drive* than fancy "new" multipath network layers.

Comment: The bandwidth is the speed at which an interface can [de]serialize data. An interface with a 5 Mbps bandwidth will deliver a throughput of less than that. For example, some of the bandwidth of a 5 Mbps ethernet interface will be eaten up by the Preamble, SoF, and FCS. Then you will need to take into account the IP header (20 to 60 octets for IPv4 and 40 octets for IPv6), the transport protocol (8 octets for UDP and 20 to 60 octets for TCP). TCP (used for files) also has overhead for synchronization and reliability.. The data throughput will be much less than 5 Mbps for file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Researching around the comments led me to two multipath network configuration options:

1. MPTCP (Multi Path TCP) - the "state of the art" solution on the verge of widespread adoption, included in current kernels. For more details: https://multipath-tcp.org, thanks to Anx for pointing me towards it. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp_net-next/wiki/):

> Legacy apps can be forced to create and use MPTCP sockets instead of TCP ones via the mptcpize command bundled with the mptcpd daemon

2. Bonding OpenVPN TAP devices as showcased in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I08A4-PWawk).

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you ***can't*** get 10 mbps with two 5mbps interfaces.

This is very similar to a network Port-Channel. I had configured 4 ports each with 100mbps thinking that I would get a speed of 400mbps, but that was not the case. The speed was still 100mbps. Apparently  something like Port-Channels or what you are doing is for 'link-redundancy'. Link-redundancy is that if one interface gets clogged up with packets or suddenly fails, it can change to the second interface for the packets and you can fix the first interface.

This is also similar to load-balancing, which is when a interface is getting clogged up it can send packets through the second interface to  avoid loads more packets clogging up the first interface.

So you should only see a download speed of 5mbps.

Comment: Multipath routing can be used to achieve higher fault-tolerance, higher bandwidth, or both. By default, many systems primarily assist setting up fault-tolerance use cases, but that does not mean you cannot have it any other way.

Comment: I know that @anx.